# HTML textarea formatting

Tags: html, textarea

If I copy the contents of a textarea into a hidden input field, would the formatting be retained? Or is there a chance it could lose linebreaks, etc.

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: welcome to Stack overflow! I think it is easy to try, or not?

Answer (score 1):

It will lose line breaks with 100% certainty because input fields are SINGLE LINE fields by design.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#input-control-types

BUT you pointed to hidden input field so I assume you meant input of type hidden 
Then answer is that it can preserve LINE BREAKS but NOT styling.

As styling is element oriented so when you'll copy anything from textarea then you are only copying 'data' not styling which is specific to 'textarea' element.

Here is demonstration. http://jsfiddle.net/WtNRX/

Answer (score 0):

[This JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jamwaffles/yRu5V/) says all; line breaks *are* lost. Typing a few lines into the textbox and putting it into the `<input>` removes line breaks. Have a look in your browser's console after clicking the "Log to console" link to see a single line.

Comment: Well, its only right for input field BUT OP asked for "hidden" input field so its wrong and doesn't fit on hidden input fields which can carry line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the line breaks get lost when copied into a text input box, `<input type=text>`, perhaps because that element has been defined to stand for single-line input. But when copying to an `<input type=hidden>`, the line breaks are preserved, and they will get passed in the form data when submitted to the server.

This applies to line breaks entered by the user. The visual line breaks that browsers may introduce are a different issue.